# Can't properly set image from JSON in tableView cell

Tags: json, swift

I have to get crytocurrencies logos and set them in tableView cell. JSON has the following structure

```
"data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png",
            },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Litecoin",
            "symbol": "LTC",
            "logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/2.png"
        ...}
```

This's my model:

```
struct Data: Decodable {
      let data: [String: Id]
}

struct Id: Decodable {
     let logo: String
}
```

According to documentation I can fetch logos for cryptocurrencies by adding ids to this URL: https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?id=1,2,3,4,5... Since I need top 100 currencies, I'm getting them this way and then sending through Notification to TableViewController.

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    func loadData() {
        
        let ids = (1...100).map { String($0) }.joined(separator: ",")
        
        guard let baseURL = URL(string: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?id=\(ids)") else {
            print("Wrong URL")
            return
        }
     
        let finalURL = baseURL
        var request = URLRequest(url: finalURL)
        request.addValue("MyApiKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY")

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if let jsonData = data {
                
                do {
                  let cryptoLogo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Data.self, from: jsonData)
                  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .getLogos, object: cryptoLogo)
                }
                catch {
                  print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

To display logos I'm using ImageView extension:

```
extension UIImageView {
    
    func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can print logo URLs, but can't set them properly in tableView cell. Could you please say what did I do wrong? What also worries me, it's that I get logos in not ascending order as I get in Postman. How can I sort string logos array?

```
@objc func getLogo(notification: Notification) {
    
    if let responce = notification.object as? Data {
        
        for value in responce.data.values {
            data.append(value)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let crypto = data[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
        cell.imageCell.imageFromUrl(urlString: crypto.logo)
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but you are strongly discouraged from naming a custom struct `Data`. It could interfere with the Foundation struct `Data`.

Comment: Maybe not so unrelated actually, which Data is this `notification.object as? Data`?

Comment: What's working what's not working exactly? Is the tableView reloaded? Is the `imageFromUrl(urlString:)` code called? What's happening exactly?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's [String: Id] dictionary, i.e. "1": CryptoLogo.Id(logo: "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png")

Comment: @Larme What working: I can get jsonData, which is dictionary that contains ID and logos. I can also print only extracted logos. What's not working: I can't properly set logos in tableView cell imageView. Two people recommend me to try libraries like KingFisher and SDWebImage. Can I set logos without libraries or it's not good practice?

Answer (score 1):

Use KingFisher or SDWebImage to load image from url. Just one line of code

```
cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: ""))
```

SDWebImage provides us to cache images automatically

Answer (score 1):

By loading your images like so, you'll run into issues where images are being loaded in the wrong cell due to:

- the time required to load them,
- your images not being cached,
- your cells being dequeued as you scroll but the associated loading tasks not being cancelled.

If you dynamically load images in a TableView, I strongly recommend that you use a library like KingFisher to easily load and cache your images, and cancel requests as cells are being dequeued.

With KingFisher imported, you can create a extension like so:

```
public extension UIImageView {
    func loadKingfisherImage(url: String) {
        self.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        self.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        self.kf.setImage(with: ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: url)!, cacheKey: url)) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    print("Task done for: \(value.source.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failed to load image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let crypto = data[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
        cell.imageCell.loadKingfisherImage(url: crypto.logo)
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Refer to https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet if you need more features.

Comment: Thank you! I've heard about it, but didn't want to use a library to get image. I'll try it.

Comment: In that case you can at least store a reference to your `task` and cancel it with `task.cancel()` whenever you dequeue a cell to avoid having wrong images being loaded in your cells as you scroll.